# What is the source of this hadith regarding angels and the language of the Qur'an?

Tags: source-identification, arabic, malaikah

[This post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/408/22) makes allusion to a particular hadith, and I recall having read something similar elsewhere.  However, I have no clue what the actual source is, or if it is even a hadith of the prophet at all.

The meaning is, in effect, as follows:

> In whatever language the Qur'an is read, the angels will take the words to Heaven in Arabic.

I would like to know if such a hadith exists.  If anybody knows of it, and can provide a source (ideally with some information regarding it's authenticity), it would be appreciated.

Comment: I have read this Hadith in the Hadith book . Ilal al-shara'i (the cause of the situations) which includes the reasons behind the Philosophy of the Islamic ordinances. it is a great work of [Shaykh_Saduq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaykh_Saduq) this book has the complete narrators chain of each Hadith.
unfortunately this book was not my own and I have backed it to its owner. unless I could wrote here the chain of narrators.

Answer (score 6):

I searched a lot for asked words in the book Ilal Al-Shara'i by Saduq but couldn't find anywhere in both the volumes.

I was unable to find it in any reliable source also. Even by the sound of the words it doesn't seems to be authentic.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: @Ashu maybe you are right but that's my answer to the question